# Find value of $k$ for a function to be continous

Tags: continuity

The given function [image]

and the domain of $g(x)$ is $(0 ,\pi/2)$.
where $[\ \ ]$ denotes the greatest integer function.
Find the value of $k$, if possible, so that $g(x)$ is continuous at $x =\pi/4$.

I thought about it alot , but could not get any start .

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we will simplify $$f(x) = \sum^{n}_{r=1}\tan \left(\frac{x}{2^r}\right)\cdot \sec \left(\frac{x}{2^{r-1}}\right)$$

So $$f(x) = \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2^r}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{x}{2^r}\right)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^{r-1}}\right)} =\sum^{n}_{r=1} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2^{r-1}}-\frac{x}{2^{r}}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{x}{2^r}\right)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^{r-1}}\right)}$$

So $$f(x) = \sum^{n}_{r=1}\left\{\tan \left(\frac{x}{2^{r-1}}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{x}{2^r}\right)\right\}$$

Now expanding summation, We get $$f(x) = \tan x-\tan \left(\frac{x}{2^{n}}\right)$$

So $$f(x)+\tan \left(\frac{x}{2^r}\right) = \tan x$$

So $$g(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln (\tan x)-(\tan x)^n\cdot \lfloor \sin \left(\tan \frac{x}{2}\right)\rfloor}{1+(\tan x)^n}$$

Now Given $\displaystyle 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow  0<\frac{x}{2}<\frac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow 0<\tan \frac{x}{2}<1\Rightarrow 0<\sin \tan \frac{x}{2}<\sin (1)<\sin \frac{\pi}{2}$

So we get  $\displaystyle \lfloor \sin \tan \frac{x}{2} \rfloor = 1$

For continuity at $\displaystyle x = \frac{\pi}{4}$

$$k = \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln (\tan x)-(\tan x)^n  }{1+(\tan x)^n}$$

Comment: So k = (-1/2)  , Am I correct